# Send automatic email to salesforce users using apex

Tags: apex, email

I want to send an email with purely text everyday to specific salesforce users. Been told Apex is the best way to do this.

I haven't written any code for Salesforce so please bear with me.

Hope you can help.

Comment: It's easier, Write a apex job which will run daily and send email.

Comment: You can schedule apex code. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) about the schedulable interface. And here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm) about how to send emails.

Comment: If you are new to writing apex code, you should try the [Developer Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trail/force_com_dev_beginner) before starting to write your own code.

Comment: Thanks all - I will take a look at the developer trailhead but I think I still will be confused.

Where do I put any apex code in, do I need a developers console?

Answer (score 0):

Apex is definitely the most scalable solution. However, if the numbers of users you would email are under ~1000, you could try a declarative solution, using the '[process builder scheduler](https://douglascayers.com/2016/04/18/salesforce-process-builder-scheduler/)' tool that Doug Ayers built and visual workflow.

This would allow you to use a flow to select the users to email and send them an email, at a scheduled frequency.

You might be able to pull this off using process builder instead of flow to send the emails, but I think would be more likely to hit limits.  I would certainly test that first and then move to flow if needed.

Comment: Thanks

I will try Apex - where do I start to put apex code in SF?

Comment: Def start w the developer trailhead modules as suggested in the comments.